# Tem como atribuir uma função para varios regras css no mesmo hover, porem com valores diferentes?

Tags: html, css

Tem como fazer uma transition em css, todos acionados pelo mesmo elemento, porém com valores diferentes?
CSS:

```
.co-la {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
    height: 25px;
    left: -37px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 0%;
}
    #skills:hover .co-la > .html{width:87%; }
    #skills:hover .co-la > .css{width: 80%}
    #skills:hover .co-la{transition:width 1s;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="secs">
        <div class="co-be"><div class="co-la html"></div><h4>HTML 5</h4></div>
        <p>87%</p>
    </div>
    <div id="secs">
        <div class="co-be"><div class="co-la css"></div><h4>CSS 3</h4></div>
        <p>80%</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hmm... não percebi bem o que quer. Onde está o `skills`no seu HTML? Você tem IDs duplicadas, isso dá HTML inválido. Pode explicar melhor, talvez dando um exemplo da funcionalidade que pretende?

Comment: Entendi.. Vou ver se consigo algo, pois preciso de algo semelhante também.

Comment: A resposta em baixo é o que procurava?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que o seu `#skills` devia ser `#secs`, e sabendo que não pode ter ID's duplicadas (por isso mudei para `class="secs"`) então só tem de corrigir:

```
.co-la > .html
```

para

```
.co-la.html
```

Nessa linha e nas outras que tiver o mesmo raciocínio.
Assim para este HTML:

```
<div class="secs">
    <div class="co-be">
        <div class="co-la html"></div>
         <h4>HTML 5</h4>
    </div>
    <p>87%</p>
</div>
<div class="secs">
    <div class="co-be">
        <div class="co-la css"></div>
         <h4>CSS 3</h4>
    </div>
    <p>50%</p>
</div>
```

terá este CSS:

```
.secs:hover .co-la.html {
    width:87%;
}
.secs:hover .co-la.css {
    width: 50%;
}
.secs:hover .co-la {
    transition:width 1s;
}
```

**e que se comporta assim: http://jsfiddle.net/js8hd/**

Comment: +1 pela resposta. votei para fechar a pergunta por não ser claro o "pormenor" que referiste.